# Zend Framework 3 BaseInputFilter::setData() throws InvalidArgumentException

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-framework3

I have a dynamic setp-by-step form in ZF3. I use fieldsets and a default form to display the current form. The default form has only a csrf token and a submit button added. The form instaniation looks like this:

```
$form = new ReportForm();
foreach($requestedFieldsetNames as $fieldSetName) {
    $form->add([
        'type' => $this->registeredFieldSets[$fieldSetName],
        'options' => [
            'use_as_base_fieldset' => true,
        ]
    ]);
}
return $form;
```

The form displays correctly, but when I submit it, the following exception is thrown when I call `isValid()`:
`Zend\InputFilter\BaseInputFilter::setData expects an array or Traversable argument; received string`

The data I pass to the form contains the following:

```
object(Zend\Stdlib\Parameters)[89]
  private 'storage' (ArrayObject) => 
    array (size=2)
      'entityType' => string 'drivers' (length=7)
      'csrf' => string '0c435d5f0ca21132ce85e26df65d2e5e-daf2a8843f01e607f23ce48a2c209262' (length=65)
      'submit' => string 'Next' (length=7)
```

The entityType is part of a fieldset. I don't understand why this exception gets thrown, when I pass a `Traversable` object to the form. Has this occured to anybody else? How can I fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It'd be good to know if you have Collection in your fieldset? Can you post your fieldset too?

Answer (score 0):

If `entityType` is a fieldset, you can not set a data to it directly. You have to provide data to element's in it. So if we say your fieldset as;

```
final class entityType extends Fieldset {
    function init(){
         $this-add([
              'type' => 'Text', 
              'name' => 'my-field'
         ]);
    }
}
```

Data will be like;

```
'storage' => [
    'entityType' => [
        'my-field' => 'drivers
    ]
]
```

Comment: The problem was that I forgot to call `$form->prepare()` in my view script.  That solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was really-really trivial, shame on me. I forgot to call `$form->prepare` in my view script. After calling `$form->prepare()`, the post data was properly set and the `BaseInputFilter` accepted the data.